# Passing in parameters to controllers from Ember handlebar actions

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I want to send extra information from my handlebars script to my controller; this is my code:

```
<a {{action "resetState" data="state1" }}>reset1 </a>
```

I can't retrieve state1 in my controller; how do I send extra strings to the backend?

Answer (score 5):

[The API says](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_action) you can pass in multiple parameters.

html and handlebars:

```
{{officename}} 
<button {{action "actionTest" "hello" "goodbye" officename}}>See parameters through action in the console</button>
```

controller:

```
actionTest: function(a, b, c){
   console.log(a);
   console.log(b);
   console.log(c);
},
```

[See it in action in this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/iwiruw/426/edit)

Answer (score 2):

You can pass one or more context objects to the action handler by including them after the name of the action, like so:

```
{{action resetState state1}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will probably also need to specify a target (target="MyApp.someObject", or target="this") unless you want the action to go to your router. If you do want your router to get the message, you'll either need to send it a defined object and have the dynamic segment be :objectname_id to get an object out of it, or use the deserialize method.

```
route: '/service/:some_dynamic_segment',

    deserialize: function(router, params) {
       //params should equal {some_dynamic_segment: 'whatever you passed in'}
    }
```

If you do send the action to a place other than your router, keep in mind that other events are all intercepted by the view, not the controller, in case you want to keep all that stuff together.

Comment: Thanks Raphael; however the problem is that I am not passing in context objects; I am only passing in arbitrary identification strings.

Comment: Does the deserialize method not work for those? If it doesn't, you might need to make a controller that handles those messages (then set the property from the view that the message is sent from), or even make a mixin so that all controllers or views can handle those messages via the reopenClass method.